# app:stackFromEnd for RecyclerView is not working in xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I have a RecyclerView defined as:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/message_list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_above="@id/message_input"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      app:stackFromEnd="true" />
```

Related code is also common used one:

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    //layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

However when I add an item `RecyclerView`, it does not respect `app:stackFromEnd="true"`. On the other hand, if I uncomment and use `layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);` programatically, it works fine. What is the problem I am missing? Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I ran into something similar. The problem is that when the RecyclerView is inflated it does read the attribute.

But then you're assigning a new LinearLayoutManager that is created in the java code. This new manager doesn't have the stackFromEnd attribute set to true (defaults to false).

`stackFromEnd` is an attribute of the manager, not the `RecyclerView`.

In my case I have this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    app:stackFromEnd = "true"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

In your xml code you don't have the `app:layoutManager` attribute so I'm not sure what manager is created for you on inflation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to Android don't recognize `app:stackFromEnd="true"`. Maybe you put it in wrong place. `setStackFromEnd(Boolean)` does the same job, but programmatically.

According to documentation:

> `public void setStackFromEnd(boolean stackFromEnd)`
>
> Compatibility support for `setStackFromBottom(boolean)`

and

> ```
> public void setStackFromBottom (boolean stackFromBottom)
> ```
>
> Added in API level 1 When stack from bottom is set to true, the list
>   fills its content starting from the bottom of the view.
>
> Parameters `stackFromBottom`  `true` to pin the view's content to the
>   bottom edge, `false` to pin the view's content to the top edge

Read these:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#getStackFromEnd()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setStackFromBottom(boolean)

Comment: It is apparent that android doesn't recognise `app:stackFromEnd="true"`. The question is why?